# Google Forms file size limit via apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

Currently the lowest selectable Google Forms' File Upload maximum file size limit is 1MB.

I would like to make that 40KB.

Is there a way to do it using the Google Apps Script?

Comment: Where did you see that minimum?  I find that difficult to believe.  It states that: `In the ‘File upload’ parameters, you can indicate the maximum file size (from 1 MB to 10 GB) and select which file types are allowed:` [Reference](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/google-forms-file-upload-feature)

Comment: Thanks. I have rephrased the question.  I am aware that it has that. However my business requirement requires file sizes to be 40 KB maximum rather than 1 MB.